# Add vector elements(Scheme R5RS)- please see revised code section

Tags: vector, scheme

I'd like to add all items in a vector in Scheme.

I believe my problem areas are in the way I use lambda (very unsure of this expression's correct usage), assign the length of the vector to variable i and add the value I attempt to get from each of the elements in the vector. Not sure how to fix the error based on the error message.

The error I am getting is just:

> ## #< procedure>

the code:

```
(define (sum X)
   (define length (vector-length X)) ;potential problem area
       (lambda (length)
       (lambda (total)
          (do (
              (i length (- i 1))
              (a (vector-ref X i)(+ a total)) ; potential problem area
              )
           ((zero? i) total)
            )
         )
         )
  )
```

Revised code (thanks user479988) - I've removed the lambdas, realized I dont need them. And defined the variable i to an initial 0.

**The error is now the output is showing 0.**

```
The code:

(define (sum X)
  (define length (vector-length X)) ;potential problem area
  (define total 0)
  (define i 0)
  (do (
       (i length (- i 1))
       (a (vector-ref X i)(+ a total)) ; potential problem area
       ((zero? i) total)
       )
    )
  )
```

Could you please advise on the 
i) error
ii) logic of the algorithm

Thanks!

Comment: Just as an aside, you're code style (layout) as shown is generally regarded to be bad form. Check out this Lisp style guide for some pointers. http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell the structure of your program because the parenthesis are mismatched and the indentation is hard to read but I think you're not giving the lambdas any input so instead of returning the sum, you return the function you made with the lambdas since you didn't evaluate them.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'd like to clarify on the lambdas: The first one should have the length of the vector, while the second is calculating the total sum of elements in the vector...how is it that the assignment is not getting done, and how I can improve the code? (sorry about the indentation, i'll edit it, not sure how the parenthesis are mismatched though, the program compiles.)

Comment: well if you just have a lambda, then it's just a procedure.  You need to supply the lambda with arguments.
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 4) will return 16 because the lambda will be fed the 4 as the argument for x.  
For yours, if you want the lambda to use the length, then you will want something like 
((lambda (length) ...) length)
In general though you don't need to use the lambda that takes in the length because you defined it already and it will be in the scope when the do is called.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the elaboration. I've amended my code based on it, removing lambda and initializing the counter variable, now the problem is the output is showing 0, i.e. the elements are not being summed. Got an idea why?

Comment: Make sure you're writing the do loop correctly and also I think you will want to use set! to change the value of the total.

Comment: Also for the do loop, make sure you iterate through the right bounds.  If you start with the length of the vector, your vector-ref will not work because vector positions start from 0.  Also, you might want to do the totaling in the body of the do loop

Comment: thanks, when i use set!, i get 'bad syntax error. and I modified the loop bounds to length-1, but it still doesnt work..did you try this out in your compiler? I'm not sure why i cant solve it still..

Comment: Yeah I tried it out and got a working solution.  can you modify your code to reflect any changes you made